# how to pass javascript callback response into php

Tags: javascript, php, json

how to pass the callback javascript response to php if let's say i'm in a single php file ?.
here's a sample snippet of e.g test.php

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
var _somestuff = _somestuff || [];
            (function () {
                _somestuff.push(['id', blahblah], ['setApiKey',   "blahblah"] 
                );
            var d = document, g = d.createElement('script'), s = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            g.type = 'text/javascript';
            g.defer = true;
            g.async = true;
            g.src = 'blahblah.js';
            s.parentNode.insertBefore(g, s);
        })();


             function myCallback(response)
            {

                if (response !== undefined) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(response);
                    var item_ids = data.items;
                    console.log(item_ids);
                }
            }  
   _somestuff.push(['blahblah',"001124","blahblah","myCallback"]);
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

what I want to happen is, display the data or the item_ids inside the html body using php.. how to do that?, i'm in a single page, I don't want to use ajax or whatever,is that possible ?

Comment: If you want to pass data to PHP so it is on the server, you need to make an http request to the server. That is how it works. If you do not want to pass it to the server, maybe you need to explain your situation better.

Comment: the function that I added was already an ajax response, is there a way to just display the content of the function inside html5 ?

Comment: what calls `myCallback`?

Comment: @sasori your question is still not much understandable. Where have you used your `myCallback` function - currently nowhere.

Comment: i edited the code again, please see, i dunno if it's understandable now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the my issue by assigning the myCallback function to a variable like

```
var a = function myCallback(response)
            {

                if (response !== undefined) {
                    var data = JSON.parse(response);
                    var item_ids = data.items;
                    console.log(item_ids);
                }
            };
```

then passed the variable to

```
_somestuff.push(['blahblah',"001124","blahblah",a]);
```

then inside the myCallback if condition, I just manipulated the html there and loaded the data response :)

Answer (score 1):

IF PHP and your JS are in the same page

- You need to use AJAX (to send a POST to the same page)
- In order to make PHP respond with some data but not with the same whole document you need to put `exit;` in the last line of your PHP code
- (Your PHP code has to be at the top of the same document.)

PSEUDO:

```
<?php
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
       if(isset($_POST["someData"])) {
           // Do some stuff with someData
           // return /*anything you need*/; // this return will be collected by the AJAX success
       }
    }
    exit; // Prevents the AJAX to return the whole document (with HTML etc)
?>
<html>
<head>
<script>
     // JS AJAX POST someData TO PHP (use the same url)
     // on success use the returned data by the PHP's `return`
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I edited my code, i know how to use the jquery ajax ..but this time, am not using jquery...please see, is there a possible way to display the response of myCallback inside the body ?

Comment: @sasori you don't need to use jQuery to AJAX the same page (to a PHP script) :) jQuery just helps you make things simpler and short.

Comment: but based from my code above, is there a possible way to just display the myCallback response inside the body tag?, because the data is already inside that function when i checked the chrome browser, i just need to know how to display it properly in html, that's why i was wondering if I can pass it to php or whatever?

Comment: @sasori I cannot see any PHP and I still cannot see how you used (called/invoked) your function.

Comment: @sasori no, it's not again understandable, 1. you didn't showed any PHP and explained what's all about. 2. you did not executed anywhere your `myCallback()` function.

Comment: @sasori sometimes it helps to describe what you're trying - not only what your issue is. Think again. PHP runs on the server, JS in the browser. Hope it helps.

Comment: the goal was, I am getting already the javascript object data , based from the javascript snippet above. but the thing is, i want the javascript object, to be assigned into a php variable, so that i can use that php variable inside the html body tag

Comment: It's already too late to use it in PHP. Use that variable from now on with JS. You dont need PHP at this stage.